# C1047 The object or library file '' was created by a different version of the compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am migrating VC++ project from VisualStudio2015 to VisualStudio2019.

One of the project reporting below error,

Error   C1047   The object or library file *'Library Path'* was created by a different version of the compiler than other objects like *'Object file path'*; rebuild all objects and libraries with the same compiler.

I tried to rebuild all the project and use existing compiler object file. But problem not solved.

Can anyone give solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error message should tell you which components need updating.  Manually delete all targets (eg exe, lib, dll ...) and intermediates (eg obj) using Explorer.  Now check for any pre-built (or 3rd party) components as these will need updating before you can build.  Close and re-open the Solution, then do a full rebuild.

Comment: I tried this project has many object file. If I change object file, it reporting another object file with same error code.  It going continuously.

Is there any possibility to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you delete all of the items I listed above (and check any pre-builts)?  If the Solution contains multiple Projects then check each project is using the same tool-chain.

Comment: Smells like a problem with the timestamp of these .obj files, maybe they came from a different machine.  Use Build > Clean and ensure there are no .obj files left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below step , issue got resolved.

Error C1047 The object or library file '**Library Path**' was created by a different version of the compiler than other objects like **'Object file path'**; rebuild all objects and libraries with the same compiler.

1. compile the reported **Library Path** project in same compiler [VS2019:Toolset 142].
2. Verify that library created.
3. clean all binary,lib and object files from issue reported project.
4. copy the new library to respective folder or If project has any pre-build step , dont copy the library file.
5. Build the project with same compiler.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve C1047, rebuild all object files or libraries by using the same version of the toolset.

[Found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1047?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Is any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can anyone give a way to resolve this issue?

I stuck up in my work due to this issue.

Comment: Since the [article about C1047](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1047?view=msvc-170) mentions compiler options `/GL` or `/LTCG`, could the incompatibility be resolved by turning them off (disabling)? Even nowadays (with VS2022) you can easily encounter this error when libs built with 17.2.6 are fed to 17.3.4